# How to get the values from an array returned by a method

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

My task is to create a coffee machine simulator, using methods. The rules are, that the machine initially has some ingredients inside, and user can buy coffee, fill it with ingredients or take money from it. The program must display the current state of machine, ask the user for the action he wants, perform the action and then display the status of the machine after the action. I figured I need to use non - void methods, and since a method can only return one variable, i chose an array as return value. But i don't know how to use that array to display changed ingredients after the action performed by the user. ATM I've completed the buying option, when I discover the solution, the rest of actions should be much cleaner to write. So here's what i got:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{



            int waterAmount = 400;
            int milkAmount = 540;
            int beansAmount = 120;
            int cupsAmount = 9;
            int money = 550;

            systemCheck(waterAmount, milkAmount, beansAmount, cupsAmount, money);

            System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take): ");
            String action = input.next();
            switch (action){
                case "buy":
                    buyDrink(waterAmount, milkAmount, beansAmount, cupsAmount, money);
                    break;
                case "fill":
                    fillMachine();
                    break;
                case "take":
                    getCash();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong choice!");
            }

            systemCheck(waterAmount, milkAmount, beansAmount, cupsAmount, money);





        }
        public static void systemCheck(int water, int milk, int beans, int cups, int money){
            System.out.println("The coffee machine has: ");
            System.out.println(water + " of water");
            System.out.println(milk + " of milk");
            System.out.println(beans + " of coffee beans");
            System.out.println(cups + " of disposable cups");
            System.out.println(money + " of money");
        }



        public static int[] buyDrink(int water, int milk, int beans, int cups, int money){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino: ");
            int choice = in.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    if (water >= 250 && beans >= 16 && cups > 0){
                        water = water - 250;
                        beans = beans - 16;
                        money = money + 4;
                        cups = cups - 1;
                    }else
                        System.out.println("Not enough ingredients, fill the machine please");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (water >= 350 && milk >= 75 && beans >= 20 && cups > 0){
                        water = water - 350;
                        milk = milk - 75;
                        beans = beans - 20;
                        money = money + 7;
                        cups = cups - 1;
                    } else
                        System.out.println("Not enough ingredients, fill the machine please");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (water >= 200 && milk >= 100 && beans >= 12 && cups > 0){
                        water = water - 200;
                        milk = milk - 100;
                        beans = beans - 12;
                        cups = cups - 1;
                    } else
                        System.out.println("Not enough ingredients, fill the machine please");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong choice!");

            }
            return new int[] {water, milk, beans, money, cups};
        }
        public static void fillMachine(){

        }
        public static void getCash(){

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should model your coffee machine as an object, that would be a start.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think is needed here too, but the it's a learning project and I can't add new classes to it yet. I guess that's the thing I'm supposed to get to know afeterwards....

Comment: You already have a class aptly called `CoffeMachine`, use it instead of trying to cram primitives into your main method.

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right:) But I still don't know if (overally) my thinking is right - I mean, returning those values as array  - and if yes, how to get them working well in systemCheck() method after running the action:)

Comment: You are trying to do the wrong thing. Java methods return only one value. Your coffe machine is stateful. Encapsulate your coffe machine in an object, and return this single coffee machine from your methods, instead of trying to put the values into an array.

Comment: Thanks! After a long battle with myself and many tries, I figured out smth like this: https://pastebin.com/Nyij1hKT . Works. Thank you!:)